# need to get the minimum number of the sets of arrays in angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on angular 4 application . I am trying to write a function that will get the minumim number and maximum number from three array objects. Here the yAxisData object contains three yaxis array objects. The funtion i have written doesnt written me the min number from the set of arrays. I can see three array objects are getting passed to the getMinY method

```
export interface YAxisData {
    yaxis: number[];
}

yAxisData: Array < YAxisData >  = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.addSeries();
    let minY = this.getMinY(this.yAxisData);

}

private addSeries() {
    this.results.forEach(element => {
        if (element.data != null)
            this.yAxisData.push({
                yaxis: element.yaxis
            });
    });
}

private getMinY(data: any[]) {
    return data.reduce((min, p) => p < min ? p : min, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
let minY = Math.min(...this.yAxisData.map(el => Math.min(...el.yaxis)));
```

What it does

- make an array of the numbers you want to compare only, made of the min of each yaxis
- spread the array with the spread operator
- get the min value in that array.

Working snippet :

```js
yAxisData = [{ yaxis: [-50, 17] }, { yaxis: [34] }, { yaxis: [46] }, { yaxis: [0] }, { yaxis: [17] }];
let minY = Math.min(...yAxisData.map(el => Math.min(...el.yaxis)));
console.log(minY);
```

Comment: I am getting the following error while putting in my code argument of type number [] is not assignable to parameter of type number

Comment: What is your `yAxisData` structure ? Edit your question with it please.

Comment: My bad, didn't see it. Here you go, I updated my answer.